# PHP: To decode json to chinese and smily not works?

Tags: php

To decode json to chinese:
    json_decode('"\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\u597d\u5bb6\u4f19\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d"');
not works?

It works for chinese but not for smily

can you please give me any idea for it

Comment: use the double quote `"`

Comment: alrady tried with both single quotes and double but not works bro
already tried by 
print json_decode("\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83");

print json_decode('\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83');

Comment: With special characters/sequences `\u` or `$` and such you should use `"` so PHP parser knows that there may contain items that need to be treated differently

Comment: PHP6 is going to^^ have [`unicode_decode()`](http://php.chinaunix.net/manual/es/function.unicode-decode.php) for that.

Comment: no, no, you have to have the double quotes _inside_ the single quotes -- the outer quotes are for the php language, the doublequotes must be contained inside the json string to be decoded.  Experiment: check what json_encode("x") returns, and feed that back to json_decode() to get a feel for how it should work; _then_ try it with the breaking utf8.  See the edit to my answer below for what it should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's not a valid JSON string -- JSON strings must be inside double quotes

Edit: took the failing example above, wrapped the utf-8 in doublequotes, and it decoded:

```
var_dump(json_decode('"\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83\ud83c\udf83"'));
string(12) ""
```

(I don't know what the glyphs should look like, I don't eve know if I have the right fonts installed, but the string decoded)

Comment: Perhaps an example is called for.

Comment: it is valid json i obtain it just like 
echo json_encode('工作');
while i was encoding chinese to json
now vice versa i wanrt to decode which not works for me.
got the point?
as it is obtained from json_encode function so it is valid json

Comment: look carefully, the var_dump output of json_encode starts with "" and ends with "" -- two sets of quotes each  `var_dump(json_encode('\ud83c\udf83'));
string(16) ""\\ud83c\\udf83""
`

Comment: IT only works in mozila firefox browser but chrome it is not working